# Unable to disable forms authentication in one of the sub folders in IIS 7.0

Tags: iis, formsauthentication

I have a website that is deployed on IIS 7.0 . The requirement i am looking for is very simple . The authentication at root level has form authentication enabled . But i need to disable forms authentication end enable windows authentication in one of the sub folders . But i am unable to do this ! I have tried differnt forums but nothing seems to work . Please help on this !

Problem is that with forms authentication enabled at the root level i am unable to disable forms authentication in one of the sub folders for which windows authentication needs to be enabled !

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me, I have used it with ASP.NET applications with Forms Authentication to disable authentication:

```
<configuration>
...

<location path="subfolder/images">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

...
</configuration>
```

However, as I far as I know you can't have 2 authentication methods inside the same application. In this scenario your described you need to create a "Virtual Directory" in IIS for the subfolder instead of making it a "Sub Folder".

The Virtual Directory will allow you to declare a new web.config where you set the new authentication method in this case Windows.

For a full walkthrough on how you can perform this please refer to this site:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb763173(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb763173%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Dalorzo thanks for your reply . The above configuration that you had mentioned , needs to go into web.config at the root level ? Is there any web.config that i need to include into the sub folder too if i am going with the approach of not making my subfolder a virtual directory ? Please advise !

Comment: The above config goes in the root level but it will only disable the security of a sub folder. My recommendation is to create a "Virtual Directory" and create a new web.config on that folder with windows authentication enabled.